# Drupal 7: How to draw all widgets for a node-add form dynamically

Tags: drupal-7, content-type, drupal-hooks

I'm working on a module in which I need to draw multiple node-add forms, from different content-types, in the same page and save them all at once. I have all the content types of every node I need to add, and I even managed to get the fields using `field_info_instances("node", $type)`.

Now I need to render the fields. I found `node_add()` but this function creates the entire form, including save buttons and publishing options. I only need the widgets for the fields.

Is there a hook or a function in drupal that will render only the widgets for a node-add form given the content type, or even the widgets for a field given it's info?

R.

PS: I'm working on drupal 7.x

Answer (score 0):

Calling node_add($content_type); will give you the node add form for this specific form type.

I'd think this way

```
$form = array();
$types = array('page', 'blog', 'article');

foreach ($types as $type) {
  $type_form = node_add($type);

  // Somehow merge this data with the $form array avoiding the conflicts
  // resulting from mulitple fields with same name.

  // and find a way to submit all of them with one button .. ajax?
}

return $form;
```